# Парсинг текста регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется текст который надо распарсить и к сожалению лучшего способа чем парсить регулярками я не вижу. Пример текста: `А здесь у нас Название (и доп информация)` и пример регулярки которую я составил: `А здесь у нас (.+) \((.+)\)`. Она работает (выдергивает название и инфу в скобках), но есть проблема - доп инфы может не быть. То есть после названия может строка просто закончиться. Не знаю как правильно тогда составить регулярку... В этом случае название должно выдернуться, а доп инфа вернуть null. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/a3Rj9Y/1

Comment: Названия из одного слова - лишь частный случай.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да. Название может состоять из нескольких слов.

Comment: [`~\h+\K\p{Lu}+\pL+(?:\h+\pL+)*(?:\h+\([^()]+\))?~u`](https://regex101.com/r/OCPf9r/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
'~^А\s+здесь\s+у\s+нас\s+(.+?)(?:\s+\((.+)\))?$~u'
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/eCSDDj/2)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `А\s+здесь\s+у\s+нас\s+` - строка `А здесь у нас`, в которой слова разделены одним и более пробельными символами
- `(.+?)` - Подмаска №1: один и более символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно меньше
- `(?:\s+\((.+)\))?` - необязательная последовательность:

  - `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов
  - `\(` - символ `(`
  - `(.+)` - Подмаска №2: один и более символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно больше
  - `\)` - символ `)`
- `$` - конец строки.